# Need to set permissions in Form Library so that normal user can only see own items but managers can see all

Tags: permissions, form-library

I am trying to set the permissions for a form library in sharepoint 2016. Standard users should be able to add and edit their items but not see items created by others. Managers should be able to see and edit all items in the library.

Information contained is sensible so it should be a secure way to implement it.

Looking forward to your ideas.
Julian